# I was trying to sending notification through Firebase console API

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, web-push

[image: Help]

I was sending notification through Firebase console API and it is giving a bad JSON format error. I have properly put the headers and authentication key and every requirement.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems you're using an incorrect endpoint. Based on the format, you're using the Legacy API so the endpoint should be:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Also, you don't need to specify the `project_id` so you should remove it in the header. You can check out this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize-legacy-protocol-send-requests) on how to build send request.

You didn't include the payload of the message so I'm not sure if they are valid as well.